# python resource limits

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess

Is there some limit for usage of subprocess.Popen..? I observed that it fails continuously at 1017`th execution of external command.

usage:
`subprocess.Popen (cmd, shell=True, stdout=file_hndl, stderr=file_hndl)`

Expecting the error and output to be redirected to file with file object `file_hndl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no fault with **subprocess.Popen**, the havoc is created by using the `file_hndl` in place of `stdout` and `stderr`.

All the resources are limited to each user process in operating system.

Ex:`On Linux` **$ ulimit -a**

core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 30254
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024

Note the number of files that can be opened is 1024, This was limiting the execution of `subprocess.Popen`.

set the resource limit as required using [resource.setrlimit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/resource.html).

Ex: `resource.setrlimit (resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE, (20000,20000))`

Answer (score 0):

You are running out of file handles. You can increase it and check;
 More info here

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36841/why-is-number-of-open-files-limited-in-linux
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84227/limits-on-the-number-of-file-descriptors

Comment: Thank you Alex, I am a new bee to python, after researching for a while figured it out :-).

Comment: Alex, is their wrong in my usage of **Popen**. I am observing that the application is gradually going slow with executing 1000 external commands.